# Unable to upload a 1GB+ file from python storage google client

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hi I am unable to upload a 'large' file 2GB to google storage form kubernetes using the google-cloud-storage~=1.6.0 client.

```
    client = storage.Client()
    self.bucket = client.get_bucket('test-bucket')
    blob = self.bucket.blob(remote_file)
    blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
```

I gave the pod a lot of memory ( 4GB+ ) thinking that it might solve it , but the master kills it any way (OOMKilled), i guess i am missing some configuration in the upload process.

Comment: did you check your firewall?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour of `upload_from_filename` is to read the whole file into memory in order to try uploading it all at once. To avoid this set `blob.chunk_size` before calling `blob.upload_from_filename`. A sensible value might be 1MiB (1024*1024).

I suspect this may be an new issue [introduced by this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/commit/d92306a31a655ee0f005918991d38d0906ffee38).

Comment: I ran into the same issue, `blob.chunk_size = 1024 * 1024` before doing `blob.upload_from_filename(file)` worked perfectly for me.